# Anypoint Studio -- How to check call heirarchy of a flow

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

How can I check the call heirarchy of a flow ? How many flows are calling that particular flow ?

for eg: if A-> B and C-> B so when I check the call heirarchy of flow B I should get Both A and C.

Can we achieve this in anypoint studio ?

Comment: What do you mean by check exactly? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @aled B is a reusable component and I am using it as a flow refrence in A and C. This is just an example.My project has complex flows

Comment: @aled Another use case is when trying to understand an existing project .Suppose, I land on a flow and to understand the flow of the project I want to see which flow is using this flow through the flow reference component.

Comment: We have this facility in Eclipse where we can view the call heirarchy of a function .It is very helpful in understanding the flow.

Comment: You want to find statically -at design time, not execution time- which flows call a flow?

Comment: Yes @aled that's right .I don't want to find it at executiion time

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a function in Studio to find statically flow reference to a flow, like for example the References in Eclipse Java editor. It would be good to have, though.